# svn diff through SSH - not same results as Trac?

Tags: svn, ssh, diff, trac

Greetings,

I'm trying to generate a diff for a revision from a remotely hosted SVN repository (hosted with codesion.com). If I view the diff/changeset through Trac, i can see the changes made in the revision. But if I'm trying to generate the diff through SSH i get no results (it gives results for other revisions though). Any ideas? Has it got something to do with the revision containing binary/non-text files?

Comment: Is it supposed that now we need to guess what you actually have tried?

Comment: You're going to have to post the SVN command you used. A common mistake is forgetting the `-c` option to `svn diff`.

Comment: I was attempting to use "svn diff -r 45 URL" to get changes between revision 44 and 45 in the remote repo. Using "svn diff -c 45 URL" works perfectly. Thanks and sorry for missing to paste the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was attempting to use `svn diff -r 45 URL` to get changes between revision 44 and 45 in the remote repo. Using `svn diff -c 45 URL` works perfectly.